# Finding a pattern of string at the start in a bigger string using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

i just wanted to check through regular expressions if my string contained the word TSS at the start...e.g TSSProd or TSSRelease1...if TSS occurs anywhere in the middle or at the last  it should return false...Please help as i have no knowledge of Regular expressions.Thanks in advance

Comment: What if it contains `TSS` both at the start and in the middle/end?

Comment: You have no knowledge of Regex? You can do something about that: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: if (str.indexOf('TSS') === 0)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var patt = /^TSS/
if(patt.test(mystring)){
    alert(mystring+' begins with TSS!');
}
```

`patt.test(mystring)` will return true if mystring begins with TSS and false otherwise.